# Asp.Net MVC 3 and changing folder for a jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-plugins

I'm playing with jquery plugins in a ASP.Net MVC 3 project, and I create a js file for some testing

If I add a reference to the file with:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/myFirstJqueryPlugin.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

everything works fine, but if I move the js file to /Scripts/Pets and update the reference with:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Pets/myFirstJqueryPlugin.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

the plugin doesn't works anymore ( I got an undefined exception )

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The plugin needs following javascript file.

**jquery.js**

Placing `jquery.js` in same directory works.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are referencing `jQuery` file and before these plugins file.

Comment: I'm using a <script> referencing jquery in the mvc view before the reference to my js file. That should be enough?

Comment: in browser check the view source, look there , and make sure jquery is getting called before these plugin files.